# Grocery crud issue with blank space in primary key

Tags: codeigniter, primary-key, crud, grocery-crud

I am using code igniter and Grocery CRUD, however when a register has blank spaces in its primary key (ie Phantom Dancer) the view or edit method from grocery crud doesnt load the field values, but if I change that name for Phantom_Dancer everything works good, does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Canonical fix: Use auto-incremented INT as a PK.

Comment: Oh thanks its simple and easy :)

Comment: The names with whitespace for a database table name is not a good practice.